# Using store and route in a third-party script (nuxt ^2.15.3)

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, vue-router, store

project on nuxt ^2.15.3. I have a class that performs asynchronous queries to the database, I need to import the store and route so that I can use them inside, now when I initialize the class in the constructor, I assign myself a router and a store, but the problem is that when making requests on different pages, the router parameter not dynamic, it does not change ,yes i can transfer store and router from asyncData ,but it is the independent use that is of interest without the constant transfer of the store and the router.

requestMongo.js

```
export default class {
constructor({ store, $axios, i18n, $config, route }) {
    this.api = $axios.create({
        baseURL: `${$config.baseURL}/${$config.mongoURL}`,
        method: 'post', // default
        headers: {
            common: {
                Accept: "application/json",
            }
        }
    });
    this.store = store;
    this.i18n = i18n;
    this.route = route; - the router is static and does not show changes when you navigate to other pages
}
```

function.js

```
export default async function ({ store, $axios , i18n , route, $config }, inject) {
const requestMongo = new RequestMongo({ store,$axios,i18n,route,$config });
inject('requestMongo', requestMongo);}
```

nuxt.config.js

```
  plugins: [
{ src: '@/plugins/functions.js' },]
```

I tried to import the store but

```
import store from '../../store'
```

or

```
import {store} from '../../store'
```

But store is `undefined`

is it possible to call the actual store and router in the class without resorting to

```
 async asyncData({$requestMongo,route,$store}) {
    return await $requestMongo.getSingleSlugPage({route,$store})
},
```

thanks for your time

Comment: Outside of `asyncData`, you can use `this.$store` pretty much anywhere.

Comment: @kissu yes, but calling in a third-party script in this way is not possible

Comment: Yes, it is feasible.